# Why can FCN use softmax as its loss function?

Tags: caffe, softmax

Fully Convolutional Networks use softmaxloss as its loss layer, but sengmentation is a multilabel task, it cann't be treated as probability problems. Do I understand something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The softmax loss is per pixel: the output (predicted) probability is a vector of length #classes *per-pixel* and the loss is `"SoftmaxWithLoss"` *per-pixel*.